# How to solve "A network-related or instance-specific error"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ssms

I know this is a previously asked question, But in my case I can connect to remote database hosted in somee.com site from SQL server management studio and also I can connect to the database from Visual studio when I'm creating the connection string. But I'm getting following error while I'm trying to open the connection from C# code. Please help me to solve this issue.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) Error Source : .Net SqlClient Data Provider

Comment: There's a problem in your code - which you should know by reading all the other discussions during your search. You did not post that code or tag the language, but you did for some unexplainable reason tag SSMS which CAN connect. So that isn't helpful.

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes, I have done in asp.net c# code, There is nothing wrong with my code as I can successfully connect and work with the local database in my PC,

Comment: and where does your ASP.Net code run? Is it on the same machine as your other successful connections? or is it in a web server on a different machine? This information should be gathered and understood as basic troubleshooting.... oh and I added the ASP.net tag

Comment: In the successful case, Both DB and ASP.Net code were run on same machine, In the failed case DB was in the somee.com site and ASP.Net code run on my pc, But I can successfully telnet the remote DB site and also I can connect and execute queries from SQL server management studio. And also I hosted the asp.net site on somee.com and tried. But same error occured and failed to open the connection

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by adding 1433 port to the connection string

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding 1433 port to the connection string